# Can I use `namedtuple` to give names to the elements of a 1D array?

Tags: python, arrays, arguments, namedtuple

`res.x` is an array I obtained by optimizing an objective function, and I want to **give each element a name** so I can use them more conveniently later. My initial idea is to use `namedtuple`, but apparently Python would just take the array as the first argument and reports the rest missing. Is there a way out? Can somebody help me?

```
from collections import namedtuple

Coef = namedtuple("Coefficients", ["alpha","beta","gamma"])
t = Coef(res.x)
```

**Traceback (most recent call last):**

**File "< stdin >", line 1, in < module >**

**TypeError: __new__() missing 2 required positional argument: 'beta', 'gamma'**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from collections import namedtuple

Coef = namedtuple("Coefficients", ["alpha","beta","gamma"])
t = Coef(*res.x)
```

By putting an `*` in front of the list, python's going to split the array in 3 differents arguments.